# Delayed jCanvas drawing of a line

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, jcanvas

I have already tried my luck and searched a lot but could not find a solution to my issue.
The function in question is supposed to draw a set of lines using jcanvas and pause the drawing according to prerecorded times.
Instead it just draws the entire lines at once.
Here is the jQuery code in question:

```
$("#start").click(function(){
        $("canvas").css("display","block"); 
        var obj = {  strokeStyle: "#000",  strokeWidth: 6,  rounded: true};
        for (i=0;i<counter;i++)
        {
            obj['x'+(i+1)] = arrX[i]; 
            obj['y'+(i+1)] = arrY[i] - 12; 
            setTimeout(function() {
                var interval = setInterval(function() {
                    $("canvas").drawLine(obj);
                }, 0);

            }, timeDiffs[i]);                               
        }
});
```

Comment: I'm not sure you mean to setInterval to 0. the consequence is that you're going to continuously draw the same line over and over again as fast as you can.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the loop finishes before your `setTimeout()` callback is run, your callback will always reference the final state of the object (that is, its state after the entire loop has run).

To fix this, you can wrap your `setTimeout()` callback in a closure. By wrapping the callback in a closure function, I am capturing the state of the `obj` variable. However, in this case, because objects are passes by reference in JavaScript, I have cloned the object (using `$.extend`) to ensure that its current state (properties and all) is preserved.

```
setTimeout((function(obj) {
    return function() {
        var interval = setInterval(function() {
            $("canvas").drawLine(obj);
        }, 0);
    };
}($.extend({}, obj))), timeDiffs[i]);
```

FWIW, there is [an extensive examination of this issue on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/750486/javascript-closure-inside-loops-simple-practical-example).

Answer (score 0):

just a simplification of Caleb531's point

```
$("#start").click(function(){

    $("canvas").css("display","block"); 
    var obj = {  strokeStyle: "#000",  strokeWidth: 6,  rounded: true};
    for (i=0;i<counter;i++)
    {
      (function(){
        obj['x'+(i+1)] = arrX[i]; 
        obj['y'+(i+1)] = arrY[i] - 12; 

        var incremental = $.extend({}, obj);

        setTimeout(function() {
            var interval = setInterval(function() {
                $("canvas").drawLine(incremental);
            }, 0);

        }, timeDiffs[i]);      
      })();                         
    }
});
```